# What is this "silent_install_wrapper.bat" program?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, android-studio

Windows 10 just opened a *Permissions Dialog Box* with the following text:

```
Verified Author: Microsoft Windows

Program Path:
"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /C
"C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Temp\silent_install_wrapper.bat"
-log C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Temp\haxm_log.txt -m 2048 > 
C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Temp\haxm_out.txt
2> C:\Users\<user_name>\AppData\Local\Temp\haxm_err.txt

Show Certificate

Info on Editor ...
```

Does anyone know what this `silent_install_wrapper.bat` file does on the system?

I was in the process of downloading the *Android Studio Sdk*, so it is likely related to that. However, I cannot find any trace of those files on my system and the Dialog Box closed itself after a few minutes. Was that something important?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HAXM is Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager, I guess Android Studio SDK tried to install it.

> "Intel® Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (Intel® HAXM) is a
>   hardware-assisted virtualization engine (hypervisor) that uses Intel®
>   Virtualization Technology (Intel® VT) to speed up Android* app
>   emulation on a host machine. In combination with Android x86 emulator
>   images provided by Intel and the official Android SDK Manager, Intel
>   HAXM allows for faster Android emulation on Intel VT enabled systems."

If it isn't installed [try installing it manually](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-intel-haxm).

The emulator should work without haxm but it'll be a **lot** slower.